# How to find out the most occurring range in a list

Tags: r, csv, numbers, character

I plotted a graph in R:

```
OBD=read.csv("OBD.CSV",header = TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
x1 <- OBD$Time1
x2 <- OBD$Time2
y1<-OBD$Vehicle_speed
y2 <-OBD$Engine_speed
par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
plot(x1,y1,type="l",col="yellow",ylab = "Vehicle speed")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x2,y2,type="l",col="blue4",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="Time",ylab="")
axis(4)
mtext("Engine speed",side=4,line=3)
legend("topleft",col=c("blue4","yellow"),lty=1,legend=c("y1","y2"))
```

**Sample data, CSV format:**

```
Vehicle_speed,Time1,Engine_speed,Time2,Engine_torq,Time3,Acc_pedal,Time4,Eng_fuel_rate,Time5
4.98,0,650,0,11,0,0,0,1.15,0
4.98,0,650,0,11,0,0,0,1.2,0.002
4.96,0,650,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.001,1.2,0.003
4.96,0,651,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.001,1.2,0.005
4.94,0.001,651,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.001,1.2,0.007
4.94,0.001,651,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.002,1.2,0.008
4.91,0.001,650.5,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.002,1.2,0.01
4.91,0.001,650.5,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.002,1.2,0.012
4.89,0.001,650.5,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.003,1.15,0.013
4.89,0.001,650.5,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.003,1.15,0.015
4.87,0.002,649.5,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.003,1.15,0.017
4.87,0.002,649.5,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.004,1.15,0.018
4.85,0.002,650,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.004,1.15,0.02
4.85,0.002,650,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.004,1.15,0.022
4.82,0.002,650,0.003,11,0.003,0,0.005,1.2,0.023
```

From this table, i just want find a the most occurring engine speed and vehicle speed or most occurring range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the most common (mode) vehicle speed, you can pull this from `table`

```
mySpeeds <- table(df$Vehicle_speed)
modeSpeed <- as.numeric(names(mySpeeds)[which.max(mySpeeds)])

modeSpeed
[1] 4.85
```

To get such a value for a range of speeds, you should use `cut`:

```
# get range categories
df$speedRange <- cut(df$Vehicle_speed, breaks=c(-Inf, 4.85, 4.90, 4.95, Inf))

mySpeedsRange <- table(df$speedRange)
modeSpeedRange <- names(mySpeedsRange)[which.max(mySpeedsRange)]

modeSpeedRange
[1] "(4.85,4.9]"
```

`cut` takes a numeric variable and returns a factor variable based on the second (breaks) argument. You can supply breaks with a single number indicating the number of breaks, or a vector, indicating the unique cut points. I included `-Inf` and `Inf` to ensure full coverage.

Comment: hi, could you please explain me how does it work                df$speedRange <- cut(df$Vehicle_speed, breaks=c(-Inf, 4.85, 4.90, 4.95, Inf))                                                                                                      Thanks :)

Comment: I got an error :( Error in cut.default(df$Vehicle_speed, breaks = c(-Inf, 4.85, 4.9, 4.95,  : 
  'x' must be numeric

Comment: According to the error, your Vehicle_speed variable is not number. You can coerce it using `as.numeric`, but it might be worth taking a look as to why it is not (maybe there's a non-numeric character somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

```
OBD <- read.csv(text = "Vehicle_speed,Time1,Engine_speed,Time2,Engine_torq,Time3,Acc_pedal,Time4,Eng_fuel_rate,Time5
         4.98,0,650,0,11,0,0,0,1.15,0
         4.98,0,650,0,11,0,0,0,1.2,0.002
         4.96,0,650,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.001,1.2,0.003
         4.96,0,651,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.001,1.2,0.005
         4.94,0.001,651,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.001,1.2,0.007
         4.94,0.001,651,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.002,1.2,0.008
         4.91,0.001,650.5,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.002,1.2,0.01
         4.91,0.001,650.5,0.001,11,0.001,0,0.002,1.2,0.012
         4.89,0.001,650.5,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.003,1.15,0.013
         4.89,0.001,650.5,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.003,1.15,0.015
         4.87,0.002,649.5,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.003,1.15,0.017
         4.87,0.002,649.5,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.004,1.15,0.018
         4.85,0.002,650,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.004,1.15,0.02
         4.85,0.002,650,0.002,11,0.002,0,0.004,1.15,0.022
         4.82,0.002,650,0.003,11,0.003,0,0.005,1.2,0.023")

> table(OBD$Engine_speed)

649.5   650 650.5   651 
    2     6     4     3
```

Or for a couple of columns:

```
tables <- apply(OBD[ ,c(1,3,5)], 2, table)

    > tables
$Vehicle_speed

4.82 4.85 4.87 4.89 4.91 4.94 4.96 4.98 
   1    2    2    2    2    2    2    2 

$Engine_speed

649.5   650 650.5   651 
    2     6     4     3 

$Engine_torq

11 
15
```

To get only the most occuring:

```
> lapply(tables, which.max)
$Vehicle_speed
4.85 
   2 

$Engine_speed
650 
  2 

$Engine_torq
11 
 1
```

Does this solve the problem?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the help. I need an O/P like this . i did this in MS Excel. My CSV file contains 82000 rows and 10 columns . .......Engine_speed....... Frequency.....
Below 600 6818
600-800      12014
800-1000         2952
1000-1200 4443
1200-1400 7824
1400-1600 9969
1600-1800 12682
1800-2000 6794
2000-2200 9922
2200-2400 3790
2400-2600 5197
2600-2800 293